# libGDX Multiplexer- removing a processor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a platform button the game screen, and I'm trying to make it so the user presses it once, clicks somewhere on the screen to draw one platform, and then if they clicked the screen again, nothing would happen.

Right now, before I click the platform button, nothing happens which is what I want. When I press the platform button, the user can click the screen to draw a platform, but, after pressing the platform button once, every time they click the screen, a platform gets drawn so I'm having trouble making it so they can only draw one. I thought using removeProcessor() would've worked, but it's not.

```
InputController inputProcessor;
InputMultiplexer multiplexer;


public GameScreen(FallDown game) {
    this.game = game;

    GAMESCREEN_STATE = WORLD_STATE_READY;
    this.cam = new OrthographicCamera(FRUSTUM_WIDTH, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT); 
    this.cam.position.set(FRUSTUM_WIDTH / 2, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT / 2, 0); 
    this.cam.setToOrtho(false, FRUSTUM_WIDTH, FRUSTUM_HEIGHT);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    world = new World(); 
    renderer = new WorldRenderer(batch, world);

    cam.position.set(FRUSTUM_WIDTH / 2, 105, 0);

    inputProcessor = new InputController(game, world, cam);
    multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();       

}
```

Then, at the end of my render method I have

```
multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

These are the listeners for my buttons and I'm just using the reset button as an alternate way to stop the user from drawing platforms.

```
reset_button.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            multiplexer.removeProcessor(inputProcessor);
            return true;
        }
    });

    platform_button.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            if (GAMESCREEN_STATE != WORLD_STATE_RUNNING) {
                multiplexer.addProcessor(new InputController(game, world, cam));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would advice you not to add and remove processors that many times (especially the one in the render method.. move that to the constructor/create method).

An easy way to achieve what you are looking for is just have a boolean variable:

```
boolean createplatform = false;
```

And then set it to true when the button is pressed and to false when the first platform is created.
(So when you touch the screen, that boolean decides if a platform is created).

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I feel stupid now. Thank you so much